# Creating universal React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-sketchapp

We're trying to create a common UI component library for both our designers and developers with React. In other words - we want to render our component library to both `react-dom` and `react-sketchapp`.

We would love to specify the structure once, the styles once and the behavior once.

We can get there (kind of at least) with projects like `react-primitives` or `styled-components/primitives`, but this approach basically stops us from having any semantics in our HTML. When all you have to work with is `Text`, you can't really specify whether that text is a `<p>` or an `<h1>`.

How have people dealt with sharing code this way previously? How can we basically render HTML (via JSX) to Sketch?

Comment: You can find an example of a single project targeting ReactJs, React Native and React Sketchapp in a boilerplate project I created - https://github.com/dmeehan1968/react-native-web-sketch-boilerplate.  Look at the demos and you'll find some limited examples of creating target agnostic and specific code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own primitives by creating multiple files targeting different platforms.

For example, if you would like to create a primitive for `h1`, you would create a file called `h1.web.js`

```
const H1 = (props) => <h1 {...props} />
```

and a file called `h1.sketch.js`

```
const H1 = (props) => <Text {...props} />
```

(and maybe specify a default style to match what you can find on the web).

When you `const H1 = require('./h1')`, `skpm` will [pick up `h1.sketch.js` automatically](https://github.com/skpm/skpm/blob/master/lib/utils/webpackConfig.js#L183). You then have to modify your webpack (or whichever bundler you are using) configuration to pick up `h1.web.js` in priority.